# Tableau- Cumulative histogram

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to try my luck and get your help regarding a problem that I cannot solve.

It's hard for me to explain the problem in words, so I built a small sample, the Existing output, and the desired output.
My goal is to create a cumulative histogram graph that compares the number of events that occurred for 2 categories. The number of events should be relative to a unique reference point for each category individually (the referenced number represents the number of weeks before/after the unique reference date).
For example, point 0 can be, for category A, on a different date than the date for category B.
(Point 1 represents one week after the unique reference date).
To create this graph, I used the running of the total function.
Current and unwanted view: for the category, A we did not reach points 1 and 2. In the current view, it seems that we passed that point- The data is displayed as a graph parallel to the X-axis up to the last point that there is data in category B.
My goal is to hide the part marked in red because from this current view, it is not clear that we have not yet reached the mentioned referenced point.

Thank you for the help!

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3k89.png)

Comment: Please add a sample (input) data for this.  It is hard to understand what x axis and what y axis depicts for your example.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for the comment. have you seen my attached screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it.  But I couldn't understand